# Click once c# deploy on different server

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I published my program using click once locally: `\Home\Publish\MyProjectName\`

Then push generated files to git, and pull changes on my server. But when i installing program, got:

> has a different computed hash than specified in manifest

P.S. i can't use ftp file deployment option.

So is this possible to somehow regenerate manifest or generate for my server.

Comment: Did you modify the content of any of the files in the clickonce package in addition to moving them around between source control and your server?

Comment: no, just click on Publish button in Visual studio, then it created new version folder. Push changes to git, and pull on my server. Then simple share this folder via Apache2 web server.

Comment: You might want to check the core.autocrlf option in git. Depending on your settings that option could be modifying your line endings in some of the deployment files and affecting the hash of the file.